# How to show $\|A\|_2 \leq t$ implies $ t^2I-A^TA \succeq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\|A\|_2$ be the spectral norm of the matrix defined as the largest singular values of the matrix.

How to show when the maximum singular value is bounded, then $t^2I-A^TA$ is positive semi-definite. Formally,

$\|A\|_2 \leq t$ implies $ t^2I-A^TA \succeq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For each $x \in \mathbb R^d$ you have

$$x^T(t^2I-A^TA)x=t^2\|x \|_2^2 - \| Ax \|_2^2 \geq 0$$

Comment: How can we show the reverse? I mean when $t^2I-A^TA$ is P.S.D. how to show $\|A\|_2 \leq t$.

Comment: @Saeed Exactly the same way: $$t^2\|x \|_2^2 - \| Ax \|_2^2=x^T(t^2I-A^TA)x \geq 0$$... The point is that you have $$x^T(t^2I-A^TA)x=t^2\|x \|_2^2 - \| Ax \|_2^2$$ Therefore, $$x^T(t^2I-A^TA)x \geq 0 \mbox{ iff } t^2\|x \|_2^2 - \| Ax \|_2^2 \geq 0$$

Comment: $x^T(t^2I-A^TA)x \geq 0 \,\,\,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\|Ax\|_2^2 \leq t^2\|x\|_2^2$. How can I get $\|A\|_2 \leq t$? It is true that $\|Ax\|_2^2 \leq \|A\|_2^2\|x\|_2^2$ but Cauchy-Schwarz is not a good idea because one may not be sure the upper bound is less than $t^2\|x\|_2^2$? You see my point?

Comment: @Saeed $$\|Ax\|_2^2 \leq t^2\|x\|_2^2 \Rightarrow \|Ax\|_2 \leq t\|x\|_2$$ Now simply use the definition of $\| A\|_2$, it is usually defined as the smallest $C$ such that $ \|Ax\|_2 \leq C\|x\|_2$ for all $x$ or as the supremum of $\{ \frac{ \| A x \|_2}{\|x\|_2}: x \neq 0 \}$... I think you are confusing $\| A \|_2$ with the so called Frobenius norm of the matrix $\| A \|_F$.

Comment: I know $\|A\|_2$ is the maximum singular value of $A$, is this what you are talking about?

Comment: @Saeed To make it a bit more clear: you defined $\|A\|_2$ as  the largest singular values of the matrix. That ,means that $\| A \|^2_2$ is an eigenvalue for $A^TA$. Let $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Then $$A^TAv =\| A\|_2^2 v$$ Multiply on the left by $v^T$ and you get $$v^TA^TAv=v^T\| A\|_2^2 v= \|A\|_2^2 \|v\|_2^2$$ Therefore $$\|Av\|_2^2 = \|A \|_2^2 \|v \|_2^2$$ Use now $x=v$ in your inequality.... And there are equivalent definitions of $\| A \|_2$, but you probably didn't cover that yet.

Comment: $$t^2\|v\|_2^2 - \| A\|_2^2 \|v \|_2^2=t^2\|v\|_2^2 - \| Av \|_2^2=v^T(t^2I-A^TA)v \geq 0$$ @Saeed  It is good to remember that for corresponding eigenvectors for the maximal singular value you actually have $$\| Av\|_2= \| A \|_2 \|v \|_2$$ (in other words equality can be achieved in your Cauchy-Schwartz approach ).

Comment: Appreciate that. I think I had to notice the notion of matrix norm which is more helpful to deriving the reverse implication (sup). Now, I have far better understanding because of your explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following facts are useful to know:

- $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $\lambda + c$ is an eigenvalue of $cI + M$. This is true because $Mx = \lambda x \iff (M + cI)x = (\lambda + c)x$.
- The spectral norm of a matrix $A$ with real entries is the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $A^T A$.
- A real symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if its eigenvalues are nonnegative.

The eigenvalues of $t^2 I - A^T A$ are given by $t^2-\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T A$. Because $\|A\|_2 \leq t$, we know that the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $A^T A$ is less than or equal to $t$. It follows that $t^2  I - A^T A$ has nonnegative eigenvalues. In other words, $t^2 I - A^T A$ is positive semidefinite.